# How to represent this FSM in GADT

Tags: scala, functional-programming, adt, state-machine, algebraic-data-types

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2przXWG2Tk&ab_channel=ScalaCon) video and learned about GADTs in Scala.

I was able to represent the below state machine

[image]

Here’s my code

```scala
type Idle
type Moving

enum Direction:
  case East, West, North, South
import Direction.*

enum Command[From, To]:
  case Turn(direction: Direction) extends Command[Idle, Idle]
  case Start extends Command[Idle, Moving]
  case Stop extends Command[Moving, Idle]
  case Chain[A, B, C](command1: Command[A, B], command2: Command[B, C])
      extends Command[A, C]

import Command.*

extension [A, B, C](command1: Command[A, B])
  infix def ~>(command2: Command[B, C]): Command[A, C] =
    Chain(command1, command2)
```

Now I am looking to change one detail. I want to give the ability to `Turn` when `Idle` and also when `Moving`. And after `Turn` Command, I want the machine to retain whatever state it was in. For example, if a machine was moving and it takes a turn, I want the state machine to retain that information.

For instance `Start ~> Turn(West)` should be `Command[Idle,Moving]` & `Start ~> Stop ~> Turn(West)` should be `Command[Idle,Idle]`

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a type parameter to `Turn` command [image]